# Relating "In my case" to a clause

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

I wrote:

> In my case **with** the same problem the following solution worked!

Is it correct to use "with" for "in my case"? I am trying to say:

> I had the same problem and in my case, the following solution worked.

But I am actually looking for a shorter way to say this sentence. or

> In my case, **having** the same problem the following solution worked!

Comment: I don't understand completely what you're trying to say.  Do you mean, "I had the same kind of problem as this.  The following solution worked for me."?

Comment: Perhaps "with" is not the best preposition to use.  "In my case ***of*** the same problem", or "When I was solving/faced with the same problem...", or even "In my case, ***for*** the same problem..."

Comment: Set off the "In my case" with a comma. Then if the rest by itself makes sense it should be OK. Meaning if you write "With the same problem the following solution worked!", is it grammatical?

Comment: @stangdon yes, I modified my question to say that.

Comment: @user3169 yeah, is that grammatical?

Comment: Your longer sentence is fine (the one after "I am trying to say..."), your shorter one, not.  You could say "In a similar situation, the following worked **for me**..."

Comment: Assuming that I can read your mind, you wanted to say something like, *I had the same problem once! This solution solved my problem just fine!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In my case** is generally used to refer to some situation that has been mentioned in previous sentences (see [because of the mentioned situation](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/case?q=in%20that%20case)), so you don't need to repeat the **the same problem**.

> Person A: Have you ever had this problem?
>   Person B: Yes, and this solution worked **in my case**.

If you want to explicitly say that you had the same problem and that this solution worked, all in the same sentence, it would be better to drop **in my case** and express it like this:

> I had the same problem and the following solution worked **for me**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "with" has been used in the correct context within the sentence you have used. but it's rare in written language based on Webster, but of course we can use it a lot in speaking language.

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Armin. We expect answers to be backed up by references.  "rare in written language"... do you have any evidence for this? Here is an Ngram that shows that "with the same problem" is pretty common. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=with+the+same+problem&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwith%20the%20same%20problem%3B%2Cc0